# how to edit database manually and update values in the android app?

Tags: android

We are developing an application called marketwatch.where we have to show prices of basic commodities,what we have to do is create  a db of commodities and their prices and display them in our app whenever we change the value in db it should be updated in our android app.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you want your applications database to be synchronized with your actual database.

You can do this by two ways:

- Pulling: which means that every time you open the application or every period of time, maybe couple of hours or something, you request from the server the updates that happened in your database, if any
- Pushing: which means that when your server has an update, it should notify the mobile app by sending a push notification to tell the client that there is an update to be fetched.

You can combine both, for example low priority updates should be retrieved by pulling, but high priority ones should be pushed to the client.

Comment: I'm using android studio and sqlite how to add push and pull classes do we need an external library .

Comment: Pulling probably you using to get the data for the application in the first place, and you can read up about push notifications here,https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the official [training resources](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html) for Sync Adapters.
Or, if you don't have any constraints for the server part have a look at [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) (from Google)